# Shortcuts to switch with effects between angles in Final Cut Pro 7

Tags: video-editing

I know that, in multiclip mode, I can switch among between different angles by setting the playhead in open mode and by clicking on a different angle. What I would like is to switch between angles using a shortcut (i.e.: "1", "2"). This would seem to be the default behaviour, except when I press "1" or "2" it just stops playing and focus goes to the "jump to" textbox.

Also, would it be possible to automatically set a fading effect for the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. The shortcuts were set to "1" and "2" on the numpad, which doesn't exist on my laptop. Adjusting the shortcuts seems to work. Still, it would be nice to associate effects to switches.